# Как правильно связать модели и кастомный класс в Laravel

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection

Не понимаю как правильно связать модель и фильтр. Реализовал через Dependency Injection в контроллере, но не нравится то, что это надо сделать в каждом методе где нужно применять фильтрацию. Было бы очень удобно, если бы модель сама понимала какой класс с фильтрами надо использовать.

Подскажите как сделать лучше.

Класс фильтрации:

```php
    namespace App\Classes\Filter;

    class QueryFilter
    {
        protected $query;
        protected $params;

        public function apply($query, $params)
        {
            $this->query = $query;
            $this->params = $params;

            foreach ($this->filters() as $filter => $value){
                if(method_exists($this, $filter)){
                    $this->$filter($value);
                }
            }

            return $this->query;
        }

        public function filters()
        {
            return $this->params;
        }
    }
```

Наследники реализуют фильтры для разных моделей:

```php
    namespace App\Classes\Filter;

    class PositionFilter extends QueryFilter
    {

        public function title($value)
        {
            $this->query->where('title', 'LIKE', "%$value%");
        }

    }

    class GasStationFilter extends QueryFilter
    {

        public function number($value)
        {
            $this->query->where('number', 'LIKE', "%$value%");
        }

        public function region($value)
        {
            $this->query->whereHas('region', function ($query) use ($value){
                $query->where('regions.id', $value);
            });

        }
    }
```

В контроллере инжектирую нужный класс с фильтрами и применяю фильтрацию вот так(использую scope в модели):

```php
    public function index(GasStationIndexRequest $request, GasStationFilter $filters)
    {
        $gasStations = GasStation::with('region')
            ->filter($request->validated(), $filters)
            ->take(10)
            ->get();

        return GasStationSelect2Resource::collection($gasStations);
    }
```

Модель:

```php
    namespace App\Models;

    class GasStation extends ListModel
    {
        public function region(): BelongsTo
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Region::class);
        }

        public function scopeFilter($query, $params, $filters) : Builder
        {
            return $filters->apply($query, $params);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class FooFilter extends BaseFilter
{
    protected $filters = [
        'min_amount',
        'max_amount',
        'min_age',
        'max_age',
    ];


    protected function whereMinAmount(Builder $builder, $value): Builder
    {
        return $builder->where('min_amount', '>=', $value);
    }

    protected function whereMaxAmount(Builder $builder, $value): Builder
    {
        return $builder->where('max_amount', '<=', $value);
    }

    protected function whereMinAge(Builder $builder, $value): Builder
    {
        return $builder->where('min_age', '>=', $value);
    }

    protected function whereMaxAge(Builder $builder, $value): Builder
    {
        return $builder->where('max_term', '<=', $value);
    }

    protected function whereFreeCreditBid(Builder $builder, $value): Builder
    {
        return $builder->where('free_credit_bid', '<=', $value);
    }

}


class BaseFilter
{

    protected $inputs;

    protected $filters = [];

    public function __construct(Collection $inputs)
    {
        $this->inputs = $inputs;
    }

    public function filter(Builder $builder): Builder
    {
        foreach($this->getFilters() as $filter => $value)
        {
            $this->resolveFilter($builder, $filter, $value);
        }

        return $builder;
    }

    protected function getFilters(): iterable
    {
        return $this->inputs->only($this->filters);
    }

    protected function resolveFilter(Builder $builder, $filter, $value): Builder
    {
        $method = 'where'.Str::ucfirst(Str::camel($filter));

        if(method_exists($this,  $method))
            return $this->$method($builder, $value);

        return $builder;
    }

}

class Foo extends Model
{


    public function scopeFilter(Builder $builder, array $inputs)
    {
        return (new FooFilter(collect($inputs)))->filter($builder);
    }

}
```

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, как модель использует фильтрацию.

Comment: Отредактировал код выше. Дописал использование в модели

Comment: Да, то что нужно! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

https://appdividend.com/2018/05/03/how-to-create-filters-in-laravel/
Надеюсь поможет, так как мне помогло)

> Спасибо, прочитал вдумчиво и сравнил со своей реализацией, понравилось
>   как подключаются отдельные фильтры через массив классов. Но ответа на
>   вопрос там к сожалению нет ( Там в модели создаётся объект класса
>   `return (new ProductFilter($request))->filter($builder);` Я как раз
>   хочу от этого уйти. Если будет 10 моделей, то в каждой надо будет
>   создавать такие объекты.

Так реализуйте не через создание объектов а через методы  этого класса

Comment: Спасибо, прочитал вдумчиво и сравнил со своей реализацией, понравилось как подключаются отдельные фильтры через массив классов. Но ответа на вопрос там к сожалению нет ( Там в модели создаётся объект класса `return (new ProductFilter($request))->filter($builder);`
Я как раз хочу от этого уйти. Если будет 10 моделей, то в каждой надо будет создавать такие объекты.